# How to remove the error from the powershell report

Tags: powershell

i have created a powershell script to run image validation remotely and when any of the service found in stopped state this will fail the script.I am getting below error while failing the script.Is there anyway so that I can hide these error from the report?

```
+ Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptHalted
```

This is the script i used to fail when the service is in stopped state.

```
$EMService = get-wmiobject win32_service | where-object {($_.Name -eq 'HP12cAgent') -or ($_.Name -eq 'HPagent12c2Agent') -or ($_.Name -eq 'HPagent10gAgent') -or ($_.Name -eq 'FarmEM10gAgent') -or ($_.Name -eq 'FarmEM11gAgent')} | format-list name | Out-String
$Servicename = $EMService.Split(":")[1].Trim()


$EMStatus1 = get-wmiobject win32_service | where-object {$_.Name -eq $Servicename} | format-list state | Out-String
$ServiceStatus = $EMStatus1.Split(":")[1].Trim()

if ($Servicename -eq $null)

{
$Servicename = "Unavailable"

}
else
{

$Servicename = "$Servicename"

}

if ($ServiceStatus -eq "Stopped")

{

throw

}

Else 

{
exit 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always try wrapping stuff in a try/catch block.

```
try {  some powershell stuff }
catch { Write-Host $_ ; or do nothing }
```